# Javscript API esri/dijit/search JSON Response

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json, search

Hello guys I am having some trouble trying to parse out the returned JSON data from a dijit search. I have the following code where s.set("value","48035") will be populated from another page so for the time being i manually set it to 48035.

```
    var s = new Search({
        enableButtonMode: true, //this enables the search widget to display as a single button
        enableLabel: false,
        enableInfoWindow: true,
        showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
        map: map
    }, "search");

    s.set("value", "48035");

//have tried the following
    s.search().then(function (response) {
        var extra = response[0][0].x
        alert(extra)
        });
//and the following
s.search().then(function (response) {
                var extra = response.candidates[0].location
                alert(extra.x)
                });
    s.startup();
```

It seems like no matter what i try or do i can not figure out how to get the returned value of x. Here is what the returned JSON data looks like.

```
{"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326},"candidates":[{"address":"48035, Clinton Township
, Michigan","location":{"x":-82.9172080701955,"y":42.554260928999781},"score":100,"attributes":{"Addr_type"
:"Postal","Match_addr":"48035, Clinton Township, Michigan","StAddr":"","City":"Clinton Township"},"extent"
:{"xmin":-82.922208999999995,"ymin":42.549261000000001,"xmax":-82.912209000000004,"ymax":42.559260999999999
}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import the [json](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/json.html) module from Dojo.  It will allow you to create a JavaScript object from your return JSON and do what you want with it.

So, if you want to create a Geometry object, you can parse the returned JSON with the `json` module, get your JavaScript object, and create it from the properties of the derived JavaScript object.

Say your object is named `returnJSON` and you want to create a `Point` from it.

```
var returnJSON = JSON.parse(response.candidates[0]);

var x = returnJSON.location.x;
var y = returnJSON.location.y;

//then create your point or whatever you want to do
```